# How to reinforce a chainlink fence

Tags: fence

I cut down some trees to clear a path in my yard for a new privacy fence but the existing chainlink fence I share with my neighbor is now tipping over. **How do I reinforce the chainlink fence without ripping it out?**

My goal is to leave the current chainlink fence in tact and build my privacy fence close to it on my side.

Notes: the existing 6' metal chainlink posts are tipping as if they are either broken at the ground or just not seated well anymore.

My thoughts were to dig around the posts and add some quick cement

Comment: You could do that to the posts, but it's not a permanent nor reliable solution. Better to replace the posts, possibly with T-Posts.

Comment: "[The posts] are either broken at the ground or just not seated well anymore." Well, which is it?

Comment: @Isherwood I assumed he meant some are broken, some are not seated

Comment: Is the chainlink on your property or theirs?  If theirs, push it the other way and build your new fence. It's their responsibility to maintain it and not damage your property.  If it's on your property and you're putting in a new fence, then rip out the chainlink entirely.

Comment: If the posts are broken, you can't just re-cement them.  You'll need to replace them because they'll be broken too high up for any real anchoring to occur.

Comment: If the posts are in concrete and are leaning, but not broken, then it would facilitate re-plumbing the posts to dig next to the concrete on the neighbor's side to produce a cavity to allow re-plumbing the posts by pushing the posts at the top toward the neighbor's property. Of course, to do this you would have to be on the neighbor's property and should check with him. You wouldn't have to add more concrete on your side. Just take the soil removed from the other side and tamp it with a steel bar tamper.